# Wordpress custom page with form without using the plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking for a solution to create page where users will be add wine or whisky descriptions (as post but not from dashboard. I need custom page with form). The form will have custom fields such as taste, smell, color, etc (author role - I as administrator must accept the post).

Comment: You can create a template for it and associate it to the post...

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: It is better for you to use some plugin

Answer (score 0):

Create a template named `page-{id}.php` or `page-{slug}.php`

> page-{slug}.php — If no custom template has been assigned, WordPress looks for and uses a specialized template that contains the page’s slug.
>
> page-{id}.php — If a specialized template that includes the page’s slug is not found, WordPress looks for and uses a specialized template named with the page’s ID.

After that you can put everything you want inside.

Comment: I know but how to put form that after posting I see a new post in my custom post-type?

Comment: I think you are not following the right direction. Maybe you need "User submitted post" or something like that

Comment: or maybe I need customize dashboard? Can I do it per role? I mean that the user sees part of the dashboard but the administrator sees everything? What do you think?

Comment: maybe it's possible if you assign 'collaborator' role to a user. As the collaborator can only write articles and send them to an 'editor'..

Comment: Can I make dashboard look like homepage? :)